# python logger's descendants - benefits

Tags: python, logging

I'm having trouble to understand the benefits of creating descendants loggers out of my root logger, in each module. For instance:

In project called "foo", module name called "bar":

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# other pieces of code, that all of them use log...
```

And same project, but in module "baz"

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# other pieces of code, that all of them use log...
```

instead of just, creating one logger object, and make other modules import and use it. For instance in same project:

```
from foo.logs import logger
# other pieces of code, that all of them use log...
```

and foo/logs.py would contain something like:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLoger('foo')
# some init logic of the logger...
```

I can get all data I need from the created LogRecord object: filename, funcName, pathname, name, etc...

Why repeat same procedure of creating a descendant logger (calling getLogger) when I use one? it may also have a minor performance footprint no?

Comment: If you have two questions, you should post to questions, so that you can get answers separately, and so that the title shows what you are asking, and so that other having the same questions can more easily find them, and so that you can accept an answer for each question separately, and so that the your questions can be assessed and handled separately...

Comment: You have more control when using multiple loggers. You can the mute your loggers as you wish, for example you can change log level of `foo.bar` logger to `WARNING` and drop the log level of `foo.baz` to `DEBUG`. You can see which module produced the log record when you are viewing the logs.

Comment: Also, if you have two questions at the same time, you should probably read [this answer to question about the amount of effort you should invest before asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/389289)

Comment: @zvone my bad, noted. It is important to me to explain that I have read and searched about this quite a lot. But nevertheless, would you recommend me then to create a new question to get my second question answered?

Comment: Yes, would do that. Remove the second question here and post it as a new question.

Comment: @zvone done. Thanks!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52207163/integrate-nullhandler-of-library-into-my-own-projects-logger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for creating a separate logger for each file is so that you can later customize what is and what isn't logged without changing the source code.

Logging is usually configured via an external file, which can be modified after the installation is installed, even by users who are not software developers.

For the same reason, there are different logging levels which can be used with each logger, in order to allow more or less logs to be produced. Then at some point, when e.g. exhaustive log data from module `a` is needed for debugging purposes, the configuration file can be modified to show `DEBUG` log level for module `a` without cluttering up the log file with debug info from every module in the application.