# Integrate NullHandler of library into my own projects logger

Tags: python, logging

I'm developing a library of my own and an app that uses that library.

I'd like to use [logging](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.html#module-logging) in both projects.

After reading [this](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library) I know that my root logger in the library should contain a NullHandler. But the part on how my using project should reach to the LogRecrods created in that library (so those will be handled alongside the project's records) is not clear to me enough.

Am I supposed to add my using project's handlers into the library main logger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `NullHandler` to the top level logger of your library, and in your application, you'll just need to add handlers to the root logger (assuming that neither library has turned the `propagate` flag off from their loggers). Any calls made to log to either library should then be passed to the handlers in the root logger.

[This diagram](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) illustrates how data flows through the logging system. The root logger is an ancestor to all loggers in the system.